# xray rest api authentication without password

Tags: api, authentication, jira, rest, jira-xray

We actuly update  xray test cases by doing a curl with JIRA username and password.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -u JIRAUSERNAME:JIRAPASSWORD --data @"reports/cucumber.json" https://my.jira-url.com/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber
```

Is there a way to  use jira api tocken or some other kind of API key to avoid using username:password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Jira server/datacenter, Personal Access Tokens are now possible, [as of Jira v8.14](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/jira-software-8-14-x-release-notes-1027133861.html#JiraSoftware8.14.xreleasenotes-tokens).

In terms of syntax, after creating the token, you can use it in your HTTP request using the "Authorization" header, having the value "Bearer <personal_access_token>"
In terms of a "curl" request it would be something like

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <your_personal_access_token>"  https://my.jira-url.com/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber
```

You can also see ahead a screenshot using RestMan.

[image: RestMan example using a personal access token]

Comment: meanwhile we have updated the official docs at: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/REST+API

Comment: thank you   Sérgio

We are using an older version of jira. Is there a workaround for the older versions ?

Comment: The cloud version  https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/REST+API, I notice wee can use  Client Id and a Client Secret for authentication. 
This isn't  available for the jira server?

Comment: Xray server/DC REST API is built on top of Jira's REST API. Xray Cloud has its own infrastructure, therefore it provides slightly different capabilities. Authentication based on client_id+client_secret is thus only available in Xray Cloud. My only recommendation is to update to a recent version (v8.14) of Jira, so you can take advantage of tokens.

Comment: Creating a token in JIRA just gives one string, it doesn't provide you with client_id and client_secret. How to use the token only for a Test Execution item in JIRA?

Comment: Client ID and client secret are some settings in Xray Cloud for Xray ApI Keys. These are not related with jora tokens whatsoever.

Comment: Xray client ID and client secret are only used in Xray cloud